# Why I'm not able to run my Application server using "npm start" command and getting the error message related to start script.I am using Ubuntu OS

Tags: node.js, npm

I am making a PERN stack(PostgreSQL, Express,React.JS,Node.JS) application. I downloaded the file from github repo, opened it in VS code and tried to run the server using the following command.
**Command:**
npm start

But I am getting this error message
**Error:**
Missing script: "start"
And when I saw the list of scripts using the command of *"npm run"*
I got this error message
**Error:**
echo "Error: no test specified" && exit 1

Here is the screenshot of the error
[image: Error Screenshot]

Comment: The first means you have no `start` script specified. The second is not an error. It's default `test` script code. Take a look at `package.json` file.

Answer (score 1):

In your case the command to start the server is:

```
node index
```

or

```
node index.js
```

Before this install node modules via:

```
npm install
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to run the `npm install` command. However, if you have already done so, you can verify if the `npm` command you are trying to run is listed in the `package.json` file.

ensure that you have the correct dependencies and versions specified in the file as well.

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that the script required to spin up the server is missing in the `package.json`. When you do `npm start` you are basically trying to run the script defined in `package.json` with the name `start`. Open your package json and search for ***scripts*** where in you should find the start script and see if its missing. You can then find what the issue is.

Make sure the `package.json` was created through `npm init` so it has the script. Sometimes scripts also have names like `run` so in that case you can spin up the server using `npm run`.

An alternative approach to run would be using `node` and the file you want to run. Like say, `node index.js`.

If you need further help then please share your package.json.

Answer (score 0):

The start script does not seem to be present in the package.json file. The package.json file should be something like this

```
  {"name": "pern-stack-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A PERN stack application",
  "main": "index.js",
   .... and so on 
  }
```

There will be a scripts section there and you need to make sure start is defined there, for example

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "client": "cd client && npm start",
    "server": "nodemon index.js",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""
  },
```